Same pending intent working with setContentIntent but not with setDeleteIntent
Android Version 14/ API Level 34
I have foreground service with a persistence notification ( from Android 14, user can swipe off ).
Everything else is working as expected.
I want my main activity to launch whenever user is swiping off my notification manually ( May be not a good idea but should be possible technically )
Below is code for my pending intent.
val intent = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext,NOTIFICATION_ID,intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

Below is the way I am setting it up for my notification
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "running_channel")
            .setContentTitle("Service running")
            .setSmallIcon(package.R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification,if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_SPECIAL_USE
        } else {
            0
        })

But it is not working, i.e. I start the service notification comes. I close the app go to my phone home screen, manually swipe off the notfication but nothing happens.
If the same thing is done with setContentIntent instead o setDeleteIntent it works as expected (this time i tap on the notification instead of swipping off).
Why so?
Note: with setDeleteIntent if i swipe off the notification while my app is open, i can see the main activity being relaunched.

"but should be possible technically" - no, that is not possible due to background launch restrictions. The delete intent is not one of the places where starting an activity from the background is allowed.
